Why am I getting a CSRF token authenticity error when trying to submit a form_with through my stimulus controller?
I connected a form_with with my stimulus controller, then added the form itself as a target and added an action to point to my stimulus controller's submit function. When I then get the form and try to form.submit() I get this error that reads:
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
My form_with html tag:
<%= form_with(model: @example, data: { controller: "nested-form", nested_form_target: "form", action: "submit->nested-form#submit" }, local: false) do |form| %>

My static targets:
static targets = [
    "skillsContainer",
    "communitiesContainer",
    "template",
    "form",
  ];

My submit function:
submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = this.formTarget;
    form.submit();
}

I tried adding a hidden field in the form with the token:
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token %>
Also tried to add the action directly to the form.submit tag
<%= form.submit "Save Sprint Goal", class: "btn btn-primary", style: "border-radius: 10px;", action: "click->nested-form#submit"%>

I have the CSRF metatag in my layout and I'm succesfully sending requests in other stimulus controllers using the CSRF.

In the mean time I changed my approach to send a fetch request to submit the form and include the form data as the body of the request. Still think it would be interesting to know if there is a different approach. It seems like when you submit the form through the stimulus controller through form.submit the token is not sent with the submission as opposed to submitting directly in the form

Are you being naughty and nesting <form> tags here? That's not permitted in HTML and leads to highly irratic behavior.

@max no, but I ran into that problem a while back and I've learned since. This time I had an actual form_with surrounding the whole form. So no illegal html going on there.

Well there definately is something screwy going on and more debugging is warranted. You should not need to manually render out CSRF tags - that's done automatically by the form helper. Does the form work if submitted manuallly (without JS)?

@max Yeah the form works fine if submitted regularly. It is just when submitted through JS that it does not work. I beleive that the CSRF code is indeed generated automatically when submitted normally but submitting it through JS must be blocking the CSRF, maybe for security reasons

I believe your issue is that form.submit() does not dispatch a submit event for Turbo (or UJS in this case?) to intercept and set the auth header with the value of the hidden auth token field.  You need to use form.requestSubmit() instead.
I believe you'll need to modify your controller's submit function to this:
submit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const form = this.formTarget;
    form.requestSubmit();
}

However, that could cause a loop.  Since requestSubmit() will in turn dispatch a submit event on the form.  For that reason, you'll need to update your data-action to be triggered by the requestSubmit event, which happens earlier. I think that will avoid putting you in an infinite loop, but I'm not entirely certain of that.
<%= form_with(model: @example, data: { controller: "nested-form", nested_form_target: "form", action: "requestSubmit->nested-form#submit" }) do |form| %>

I'm curious about the motivation for intercepting a form's submission in order to re-submit it via a Stimulus controller, though. Would you mind sharing your reasoning for this? Thanks!

Thank you for your answer, I haven't had the chance to try this out yet since I changed the submit to an ajax request instead and passed the CSRF token that way. I'll try my best to explain my reasoning. The reason I set this up the way I did is because the form itself is quite dynamic. A user can add rows and remove rows from different sections of the form. These rows autopopulate based on exisitng models. And the user needs to be able to remove rows which in turn will remove instances of a model. These instances need to be destroyed before the form can be updated. Hope that makes sense..

When you manually submit the form using form.submit() in your Stimulus controller, you bypass the built-in Rails behavior that handles AJAX submissions. As a result, the necessary CSRF token may not be included in the request, leading to the "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" error.
Send AJAX request like this.
<%= form_with(model: @example, data: { controller: "nested-form", nested_form_target: "form", action: "submit->nested-form#submit" }, local: true) do |form| %>

